# Laravel Observers occasionally fails to fire after saved action

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel Version: 5.5.*

PHP Version: 7.1.9

Database Driver & Version: MYSQL 5.7.19

**Description**:

We recently updated our app from Laravel 5.4 to 5.5 a couple about a month ago and about 5 days ago we started experiencing some irregularities with our observers. Our app is an accounting software and this is a typical flow of a basic transaction.

Transaction details are entered and validated before submission and on success
The Transaction Journal entry and respective line items are created
And if the above 2 are successful, the transaction is saved and the observer fires on a saved action
to increase the balance of the respective general ledger account.
The problem
In some unique scenarios all the above 2 steps run successfully but the observer either fails to fire or if at all it does, it fails to update the balances.

**Question**

Is there a way to detect failed action inside an observer? or at least trigger a failed response?

Also if at all there's a better way we can achieve the same result, please advice.

Example:

Consider a User model that updates Customer tables with a count of customers on creation.

```
class User extends Model {
    protected static function boot()
    {
        User::created(function (Model $model) {
            //increment number of specified customer type
            $customer = $this->customerType;
            $customer += 1;
            $customer->save();
        });
    }

    //returns an instance of the customer type for specified user
    public function customerType()
    {
        return $this->belongTo(CustomerType::class);
    }
}
```

Issue arises when many requests are sent at the same time.

Current count: 3

If 2 new users try to update the field at the same time and a 3rd user comes into play, these are the outcomes

new User 1: finds the count at 3 and will update it to 4

new User 2: finds the count at 3 and will update it to 4

new User 3: finds the count at 4 and will update it to 5

In the above scenarios, the count will end up being 5 instead of 6.

Comment: No code no joy, you need to try reproducing this in a empty L5.5 project and see whats different, also debugging "sometimes" is not that fun; slap `Log::info()` where you can. Good Luck!

Comment: What driver are you using for your events? Queue? Or your events and observers run synchronously? Also, as @Kyslik said, maybe a little code could be useful for someone trying to help you.

Comment: Additionaly, have you followed the [migration guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade) when migrating? There are a couple changes related to events and queues there.

Comment: @Kyslik i have failed to reproduce it on my local and this is only happens in production and not always. Ever since it's launch it has i've noticed it only about 4 occurrences.

Comment: @pirupius do you expect us to investigate from no code, no access, no environment state? I fear, we can not help you at all. If you can reproduce anywhere you may get further in this, but I doubt anyone on SO is capable of answering this without the necessary information. Try different queue services, use database / redis or sync and slowly get to it.

Comment: Can we see the //$vendors->increment(); code?

Comment: @mrhn I've edited the code snippet to reflect the actions